# Morphism decomposition

Tags: category-theory

The category **Set** has the property that any morphism *f* can be decomposed into an epimorphism $e$ and a monomorphism $m$ with $f$ = $m\circ e$. (The intermediary set object is the image of $f$.)

Is there a name for this construction?

Is there a name for this property of categories?

In **Set**, the intermediary object is unique up to isomorphism. Is this the case for all categories with the property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of this idea is [factorization system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_system) and a lot is known about them. See the online available book "[Abstract and Concrete Categories](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf)", chapter IV, for example. A trivial counterexample to the statement that the intermediate object is unique: the poset with elements $A,B$ where $A \leq B$, you can factor the morphism $f : A \to B$ as $f \circ \operatorname{id}$ and $\operatorname{id} \circ f$ yet $A$ and $B$ are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

A related notion is that of an [exact category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_category). That's what led me to [this mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41998/exact-categories-which-are-not-additive), which could be exactly what you are looking for. In your further search efforts, it might help to search for "every morphism factors as an epimorphism followed by a monomorphism" - it seems to be a more widespread formulation of the property you describe.